# Format Specific Cell in DataTable in R

Tags: r, dt

How can I format a specific cell with DT? In this example, how would I format every cell in the first column that is >0?

```
df = data.frame(
  V1 = c(5, -31, '-2'),
  V2 = c(-5, -7, '2'),
  V3 = c(4, -10, '22'))


DT = datatable(df) %>%
  formatStyle(...)
```

I thought something like `backgroundColor = styleInterval(0, c('red', 'blue))` (in the `formatStyle()`) might work, but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below link for me is quite useful - has a variety of formatting permutations...

https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

Specific to a column, which changes based on  > 0:

```
library(DT)

df = data.frame(
  V1 = c(5, -31, '-2'),
  V2 = c(-5, -7, '2'),
  V3 = c(4, -10, '22'))

DT = DT::datatable(df) %>%
     formatStyle('V1', backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(0),c('red','blue')))
```

Might have been the c() specifying the cuts as a vector...

---

**Below is an example to format cells (but is a slight hack - not sure myself of another way)**

```
  df = data.frame(
    V1 = c(5, -31, '-2'),
    V2 = c(-5, -7, '2'),
    V3 = c(4, -10, '22'))
```

Now create a column which has  your 'flag' value

```
  df$FLAG <- c(0,0.5,1)
```

Now create your choice of styles/colours and format the data frame (I then make the FLAG (4) column not visible so looks as if cells are formatted)

```
styles <- c("rgb(245,242,242)",
        "rgb(254, 204, 116)","rgb(255,83,83)")


datatable(df, caption = 'Test Format',
          options = list(dom='t',columnDefs = 
                                  list(list(visible=FALSE,
                                                targets=4)))) %>%
          formatStyle("V1","FLAG",
                 backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0,0.5,1),styles))
```

Note dom='t' just leaves out data table filtering and paging; And columnDefs is used to leave out the FLAG column

Comment: This works...wow! Thank you. I have been unable to solve this problem for a while now. Do you know if there is a way to restrict it to certain rows as well? The `formatStyle()` specifies the column `V1`, is there any way to restrict to, say, row 3 only? I'm looking at the link you posted and it seems like there is only a way to highlight the entire row, not a specific cell.

Comment: I haven't really been able to get cell formatting correct without a slight hack, the formatStyle doesn't seem to take a cell reference e.g  [row,column] , so I create a synthetic column and format based on that, I'll include an example...

Comment: Thanks!! Slightly cumbersome, but I cannot find any better solution for cell specific formatting.